# App Service with Google authentication - list users

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

My website is deployed to Azure as a App Service. It has Google authentication set up using Azure's Google Authentication provider.

Is it possible to list users (at least name and email address) accessing my site via Google account?

Comment: Are you storing the information about the authenticated users coming to your website somewhere?

Comment: Google oauth authentication is not implemented by me in my website. I use buildin Google Authentication provider from Azure (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-google-authentication). I have no idea, how Azure stores informations about users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get information about the users who log into your web app as they log in. However, App Service does not automatically store this information in a way where you can query *all* users. It's up to you to store the user information in a way in which you can query it later. If you're trying to figure out how to get the information for each user, see below.

One option is to use the `x-ms-client-principal-name` request header to get a display name for the logged in user. If you want more information, you can get the set of "claims" for the logged in user. There are a few ways to do this:

1. If you're using ASP.NET (full framework), you can use the [ClaimsPrincipal.Current](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.claims.claimsprincipal.current%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) static property to get information about the current user. In particular, the [Claims](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.claims.claimsprincipal.claims(v=vs.110).aspx) property will contain several different properties.
2. No matter what language/framework you're using, you can make an HTTP request to the /.auth/me endpoint of your web app to get information that is automatically captured by App Service about the logged in user. This is generally going to be the same information as #1. This HTTP call will need to be authenticated using the same mechanism that was used to access the site.
3. Google has a set of APIs you can call to get detailed information about a user. To access these APIs, you need an access token, which you can obtain from the `x-ms-token-google-access-token` HTTP request header.

In all cases, you need to make sure that you've enable the correct scopes when you configured your Google authentication in the portal. This ultimately controls what information is available to your application. When users log in for the first time, they will be asked to consent to granting your app access to this information. Once consented, you'll get access to the latest information every time they log in.